# How is a React component called with parameters via a route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

The RouteParamPage.tsx is a React component that can consume URL parameters via the router. It is working.
The call is like this:

```
<Route path={"/p2/:lastname"} component={RouteParamPage}/>
```

The ParamPage.tsx component has a parameter in the signature.
I can call these components without a router like this:

```
<ParamPage label={"with params V2"}/>
```

The question is, how can I call the ParamPage.tsx component in the Route?
That doesn't work:

```
<Route path={"/p1"} component={ParamPage  label={"with params V2"}}/>
```

Does somebody has any idea?

----------------- RouteParamPage.tsx --------------

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

interface RouteParams {
    lastname: string
}

export default function RouteParamPage() {

    const params = useParams<RouteParams>();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>{params.lastname}</h1>

        </React.Fragment>
    )

}
```

----------------- ParamPage.tsx --------------

```
import React from 'react';

type childProps = {
    label: string,
}

export default function ParamPage( data: childProps ) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>{ data.label }</h1>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

----------------- Main.tsx --------------

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import ParamPage from "./ParamPage";
import RouteParamPage from "./RouteParamPage";

export default function Main() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ParamPage label={"with params V2"}/>  {/*<<<<this works*/} 

            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={"/"} exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path={"/p1"} component={ParamPage  label={"with params V2"}}/>   {/*<<< That doesn't work:*/}
                    <Route path={"/p2/:lastname"} component={RouteParamPage}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use render props to pass parameter to the component which is render by the `Route` component like this

```
<Route path="/p1" render={(routeProps) => {
    return <ParamPage  label={"with params V2"}} {...routeProps}/>
}} />
```

To learn more about check the React [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) Documentation

Answer (score 0):

For this case, there is a [**render**](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop which needs to be used instead of component.

The code will be modified to below

```js
  <Route 
    path={"/p1"}
    render={(props) => <ParamPage {...props} label={"with params V2"} />}
 />
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/confusions.